# C# String Query how many / characters it contains

Tags: c#, string

I would like to inquire how many **/** are in a string.
When I get the number how can I get all folders now (So how can I separate them)?

---

For Example: Folder/Cats (1 / = 2 folders) String1 Folder, String2 Cats

---

I first ask whether there is any **/** in the string

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"[/]{1}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    Match matchSuccess = myRegex.Match(string);
                    if (matchSuccess.Success)
                    {
                        // Create several folders
                        // Folder/Cats....

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create only one folder
                        // Folder
                    }
```

---

String Examples:

• `Folder/UnderFolder/Cat/Pics`

• `NewFolder/Cats`

• `Folder`

• `NewFolder`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? From the current scenario, it seems regex is a bad choice!

Comment: I have Regex only in the first moment, since I first wanted to query whether there is any / in the string is present. 
I want to get the number of /. 
And the folders with a / are separated.

Comment: use linq to get count `int count = yourString.Count(f => f == '/');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the number of occurrence of `/`, what you can do is use the `Split.Length`

```
int count = folderString.Split('/').Length - 1;
```

As for the name of the folders, you can get them by calling the index

```
folderString.Split('/')[index]
```

Here's the whole console app code for that:

```
string folderString = @"Folder/UnderFolder/Cat/Pics";
int count = folderString.Split('/').Length - 1;
for(int x = 0; count >= x; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(folderString.Split('/')[x]);
}
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", count);
```

The output would be:

```
Folder 
UnderFolder
Cat
Pics
Count: 3
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. That helped a lot. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standart [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
`Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4")`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go for regex. Finding any characters in a string or splitting a string is very easy. Sample code for your case :

```
        string input = @"Folder/UnderFolder/Cat/Pics";
        string[] values = input.Split('/');
        int numOfSlashes = values.Length - 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Slashes = " + numOfSlashes);
        foreach (string val in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Your folder path
        string yourFolderPath= @"C:/Folder/UnderFolder/Cat/Pics";
        //If you want to count number of folders in the given folder path
        int FolderCount = yourFolderPath.Count(s => s == '/');
        //If you want to create folder you can use directly below code
        Directory.CreateDirectory(yourFolderPath);
```